# Pointers, C++...code not working

Tags: c++

This is the question:
Write the definition of a function  minMax that has five parameters. The first three parameters are integers. The last two are set by the function to the largest and smallest of the values of the first three parameters. The function does not return a value.

The function can be used as follows:

```
int a = 31, b = 5, c = 19, big, small; 
minMax(a, b, c, &big, &small); /* big is now 31; small is now 5 */
```

This is my code:

```
void minMax(int x, int y, int z, int* big, int* small)
{
  if (x < y && x < z)

    *small = x;

  else if (y < x && y < z)

    *small = y;

  else if (z < x && z < y)

    *small = z;

  if (x > y && x > z)

    *big = x;

    else if (y > x && y > z)

    *big = y;

  else if (z > x && z > y)

    *big = z;
  }
```

This is the error I'm getting:

Your function did not change the value of `small`.  Make sure you are dereferencing it in your function.

Not sure what's wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: The problem states the signature that you're supposed to use: `minMax(a,b,c,&big,&small)`

Comment: @irrelephant, Oops, didn't catch that part. My eyes don't like reading unformatted code.

Comment: This compiles and gives the desired output for me ..

Comment: @irrelephant Do you mean to use a,b,c instead of x,y,z?

Comment: I meant `&big` and `&small`.

Comment: @Ghost_000_cs But isn't *big technically an int? Because the address will point to it...

Comment: And where are you getting the error message from? A judge of some sort?

Comment: I notice the problem description has nothing to say about the use of `std::max` and `std::min` ;)

Comment: @irrelephant Tried it but still not working. This is for turningscraft codelab, it gives me an error

Comment: @irrelephant, there's a good chance it's coming from a test harness meant to test this function. It's like no compiler error I've seen before and probably the test harness sets the values to -9999 or something then calls the function with various inputs and checks the outcome. That's why I positied 1,1,7 as test data that would break this code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I see one *immediate* problem.

What do you think will happen when you pass the numbers `1`, `1` and `7`?

Perhaps you may want to consider the use of `<=` and `>=` rather than just `<` and `>`.

Since that error message looks nothing like any compiler error I've seen before (and the code *is* valid syntactically), I'd suggest the message is coming from a test harness which probably:

- sets the `big/small` values to numbers other than those being passed in (eg, `-9999`).
- calls the function with test data (eg, `1,1,7`).
- checks the output varibales to ensure they've been changed to the correct values.

In addition, it's not the most *readable* code in the world (no offence intended). If you can structure your code in such a way that its intent is clear from a glance (including comments where appropriate), you'll have hordes of future programmers singing your praises and worshiping your name :-)

Something like this shows the intent a little more clearly (IMNSHO) than lots of those `else if` constructs:

```
// Populate big/small based on max/min of x, y and z.

void minMax (int x, int y, int z, int *big, int *small) {
    // Set by default to x, only change if others are bigger.

    *big = x;
     if (y > *big)   *big = y;
     if (z > *big)   *big = z;

    // Same for small but with reversed comparisons.

    *small = x;
     if (y < *small) *small = y;
     if (z < *small) *small = z;
}
```

Comment: Either the test harness or the problem specification is broken. The problem specification does not require changing the value of `small` if there is no smallest value. Yet the test harness complains that the value of `small` wasn't changed even if there is no smallest value.

Comment: @David, that may be a matter of semantics. Is the smallest of the set `{1,1,1}` `1` or nothing (because there is no smallest)? I tend to lean toward the former in that `1` is the smallest value in the set. Now, if it had said the smalles _single_ value, that may be different.

Comment: @paxdiablo: I would say of the set `{1,1,1}`, none of the values is the smallest. I would argue that by definition, only one of them can be the smallet, and it can only be so if it is smaller than each of the other values.

Comment: -1 providing full code solution for homework assignment (even if it's partially explained). please don't do that.

Comment: @paxdiablo: To be precise, there's a smallest value. But there is no "smallest *of* *the* values". None of the three values is the smallest.

Comment: @Alf, the problem had already been solved with my hints, the rest was just explaining how to be a better programmer. In any case, the homework assumption is just that (tho' a strong one). I have no problems giving full solutions since my intent is not to help the OP (they'll fail for plagiarism if they copy verbatim, or their educators are idiots who haven't mastered basic web searches), it's to help everyone who comes afterwards.

Comment: @paxdiablo: i don't buy that at all.

Comment: Well, that's your right, @Alf, I just explained why I do what I do. Your inability to believe that doesn't really worry me that much :-) We should probably agree to disagree so as to not clog up the comments system.

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure what isn't working. It seems like that would basically work but could be better structured.

Maybe something like this:

```
void minMax(int x, int y, int z, int* big, int* small)
{
    *big = *small = x;

    if (y > *big)
        *big = y;
    if (y < *small)
        *small = y;
    if (z > *big)
        *big = z;
    if (z < *small)
        *small = z;
  }
```

Comment: -1 it's decidedly *not nice* to provide full code solutions to homework assignments. the answer also fails to explain what's wrong with the original code. indeed, it says you don't know what's wrong with it, so that if the presented code does work, it is by happenchance.

Comment: I think you missed a couple of things there, but whatever. Do whatever you like.

Answer (score 0):

The error message

> Your function did not change the value of `small`. Make sure you are dereferencing it in your function.

… appears to come from a test harness provided to you by your teacher.

Anyway, it's correct: there are values that you can choose where your function will *not* assign anything to `*small`.

For example, with `a`, `b` and `c` the *same* value, your function will do nothing at all.

---

Anyway,

for future questions, please provide a **complete example program** that demonstrates the issue.

So that people will not have to guess and use unreliable telepathy.

---

Also, the assignment calls for you to implement a function with an *ungood signature*.

It teaches a Bad Way™ to design functions.

Here is a possible ordinary C++ function signature:

```
void getMinAndMax( int& smallest, int& largest, int a, int b, int c )
```

Here is an even better signature with modern C++ technology:

```
std::pair<int, int> minAndMax( int a, int b, int c )
```

The absence of a `get` prefix for the latter function's name  is because it is an expression-oriented function, like `sin` and `cos` (you wouldn't write `getSin` or `getCos`, would you?), while the presence of that prefix for the first function is merely to make the name imperative, to reflect that it's not an expression-oriented function but instead an action-oriended function.

Of course, with C++11 one would let the function accept any number of arguments. Except that as I'm writing this, Visual C++ does not yet support that properly. For example, here is the signature of `std::min` from the C++11 standard library:

```
template<class T, class Compare>
T min(initializer_list<T> t, Compare comp);
```

With C++03 one can do that *to some degree* by accepting a single container argument, of templated type.